# Read a PNG and JPEG image with world file in Java

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, java, geotools, png

I have a program where given an image I want to read the coordinates for each pixel.
I have implemented the code if the given image is a TIFF image and it works fine. The code that gives me the object with the coordinates is as follow:

```
File f = new File("image.tiff");
GridCoverage2D image = new GeoTiffReader(f).read(new GeneralParameterValue[]{policy, gridsize, useJaiRead});
Rectangle2D bounds2D = image.getEnvelope2D().getBounds2D();
bounds2D.getCenterX();
GridGeometry2D geometry = image.getGridGeometry();
```

I want to try now to read the same image but in another format (JPEG and PNG).
I have downloaded the images and each has a world file (pgw/jpw) and an aux file.

How can I obtain the same output I have on the TIFF file for these formats?

I am new to Java and geotools so I am a little lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer! As Ian said I just needed the dependency for the world file. The code that reads the TIFF, JPEG or PNG is below:

```
try {
            ParameterValue<OverviewPolicy> policy = AbstractGridFormat.OVERVIEW_POLICY.createValue();
            policy.setValue(OverviewPolicy.IGNORE);
            ParameterValue<String> gridsize = AbstractGridFormat.SUGGESTED_TILE_SIZE.createValue();
            File file = new File(path);
            ParameterValue<Boolean> useJaiRead = AbstractGridFormat.USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD.createValue();
            useJaiRead.setValue(true);

            //starts reading here
            AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat( file );
            GridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader( file );
            GridCoverage2D image = reader.read(new GeneralParameterValue[]{policy,gridsize,useJaiRead});
            GridGeometry2D geometry = image.getGridGeometry();
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
            WritableRaster raster =img.getRaster();
            return new Pair<>(geometry,raster);

        }catch(Exception e) {throw new Exception("Error reading the image: "+e);}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the world image plugin and everything should be fine with no changes.

Comment: But my question is how to call it in Java.I think I have the necessaries dependencies in my program. I am just not sure how to read the images and the world file and put those together in order to obtain an object with the coordinates associated to each pixel.